# How to connect node API to specific mongoDB db / collection on my local machine

Tags: node.js, mongodb

This has probably been asked before because of how high level the question is, however I couldn't find a solution and am struggling to get this set up. I am working on my first full stack web app using MERN stack. I am on a Mac. Everything I'm doing here is on my local machine.

**For MongoDB**, I have it installed on my local machine. I have the mongod dameom running. Here's what I have in my interactive mongo shell:

```
// run in terminal
> mongo

> show dbs
admin              0.000GB
config             0.000GB
mydboverhere       0.064GB
local              0.000GB

> use mydboverhere
switched to db mydboverhere

> show collections     
table_one
table_two
andathirdtable
```

I would like to connect my node/express API to the *mydboverhere* database. In my node directory structure, I have a *models* directory with:

**/models/index.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.set('debug', true);

// is this line correct? 
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mydboverhere/table_one');

mongoose.Promise = Promise;
module.exports.Todo = require("./table1"); // this requires table1.js
```

and **/models/table1.js**

```
// this matches the form of the data in the database, I believe 
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var tab1Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { 
        type: String,
        required: 'cannot be blank'
    },
    completed: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    created_date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
})

var Table1 = mongoose.model('Table1', tab1Schema)
module.exports = Table1;
```

I believe I have my **/routes/tableroutes** file correct:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var db = require('../models')

router.get('/', function(req, res){
    // res.send("Hello from the table1 route")
    db.Table1.find()
        .then(function(data) {
            res.json(data);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            res.send(err);
        })
});

module.exports = router;
```

and also I think I am loading these routes into my **root /index.js** file correctly as well:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express();

var tableRoutes = require('./routes/tableroutes');

// test the root route
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send("Hello from the Root Route")
});

// set base route to /api for my tableRoutes    
app.use('/api', tableRoutes); 

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))
```

Unfortunately, with mongod running, when I try to run node index.js to get my node app running, I receive the following error message in my command line:

*... (node:66245) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Unsupported host 'localhost:27017/mydboverhere/table_one', hosts must be URL encoded and contain at most one unencoded slash ...*

And I'm stuck here right now... pretty much, i'm not sure if Im connecting my node API with mongodb correctly or not. This is all being done on my local machine, and I have mongodb installed at /data/db as it should be. Maybe the error is due to the underscore in the collection name table_one. Maybe the error is because the data in the table_one collection in mongo doesnt' match exactly with the schema in table1.js (I created the mongodb separately by pushing a dataframe from R into it, and then wrote the table1.js schema to match it).

Regardless of which of the following above issues is **the issue**, I'm not sure, and I'm struggling to continue. Any help here is greatly appreciated!

EDIT1: I have a strong feeling that the following line:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mydboverhere/table_one');
```

is incorrect, and am seeing the proper way to connect to a specific db.

EDIT2: I think there's another javascript library called mongoDB for this, but I would very much prefer to get this working with mongoose.

Comment: I think you have a typo with the name of the db in your url

Comment: tweaked that, thanks - was an issue with my stackoverflow post but not w/ my actual code.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is an error here:

You are using `thisdboverhere` whereas it should be `mydboverhere`.

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mydboverhere', function(){
 // do your process here
});
```

Or

```
 mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mydboverhere');
  var db = mongoose.connection // I think you are forgetting to instantiate the connection here
```

Comment: Ive fixed that, mistake on my part when creating the post, since I changed the db name for the post since my actual db name has personal info in it

Answer (score 1):

From [this good github post here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2461), I found the following:

```
Make sure you're connecting to the same database 
(mongoose.connect('mongodb://hostname:27017/<db name here>')) 

and accessing the same collection 
(mongoose.model('<model name>', schema, '<collection name here>'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party,  but I had the same error message.  Removing the underscore in the database name fixed it for me.

My original database name I tried was:

`const URL_MONGODB = "mongodb://localhost:27017/portfolio_db";`

I removed the underscore, and used this database name:

`const URL_MONGODB = "mongodb://localhost:27017/portfoliodb";`

After which, I no longer got the error   "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Unsupported host 'localhost:27017/data/db', hosts must be URL encoded and contain at most one unencoded slash"